# moderncv: Change name order without losing format

Tags: fonts, moderncv, bold

I want to exchange the order of family name and first name, without losing the dark gray format. Thanks!
[image: Change John and Doe order]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. For an help, please, can you add a complete .tex code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the picture I can see that you are using style `casual`.

In style `casual` the definition for the name headline is

```
{\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@lastname}
```

To change the order of firstname and lastname to lastname and firstline you have to use the line

```
{\color{color2}\@lastname} {\color{color2!50}\@firstname}
```

You have to patch command `\makecvhead` like this:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}%
  {
    {\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@lastname}\fi%
  }%search
  {
    {\color{color2}\@lastname} {\color{color2!50}\@firstname}\fi%
  }%replace
  {}%success
  {fehler}%failure
\makeatother
```

With the following complete MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{casual} % casual, classic, banking, oldstyle and fancy
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
\social[twitter]{jdoe}
\social[github]{jdoe}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-golden-upright}%
\quote{Some quote}

\setlength{\footskip}{66pt}

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\patchcmd{\makecvhead}%
  {
    {\color{color2!50}\@firstname} {\color{color2}\@lastname}\fi%
  }%search
  {
    {\color{color2}\@lastname} {\color{color2!50}\@firstname}\fi% <=====
  }%replace
  {}%success
  {fehler}%failure
\makeatother % <========================================================


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution--3}{City--4}{\textit{Grade}--5}{Description--6}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\end{document}
```

you get the following first page:

[image: resulting first page]